# How would I find the acceleration of this vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

So I found the velocity already (which my homework says it's correct). The velocity is $\mathbf{i}+2t\mathbf{j}+4\mathbf{k}$.

I know the acceleration is the derivative of the velocity. I found it to be $1+2\mathbf{j}+4$ , but when I enter it in my hw, it says, "Operands for '$+$' must be of the same type". i also tried $2\mathbf{j} +5$ and it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The derivative of $i$ is not $1$.  Also, you cannot add a vector $2j$ and a scalar $5$ (at least, not in the regular approach to vectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v(t)=(1,2t,4)$, so $v'(t)=(0,2,0)$, so $v''(t)=(0,0,0)$.